# Define Data rules in XSD referring to other data?

Tags: xml, configuration, xsd

Is it possible in an XSD definition to define rules like
- an ID that has to be unique across the whole XML file
- a number that relates to another number, i.e. must be bigger than the number of a previous element?
- a reference, i.e. a value that references the id of another element

How would you deal with such requirements that you have against an XML?

Example:

```
<page id="123">
   <name>Charles</>
</page>
<wizard>
   <page ref="123">
   ...
</wizard>
```

In that case, customer id must be unique and the reference from order to customer must be valid, i.e. refer to a customer existing in the XML.

I'm not trying to mimic a database here, I have a complex configuration file and I'm searching for a good way to fix its definition and have a more secure way of editing/validating it.

Answer (score 0):

In XSD 1.0 you can define simple uniqueness and referential integrity constraints (values that must be unique, values that must reference IDs of other elements) - read about xs:unique, xs:key, and xs:keyref.

More complex constraints, such as "must be bigger than the number of a previous element" require XSD 1.1 assertions.